# What is the minimum SDK version should I choose? (as in July 2019) and why?

Tags: android, minimumosversion

My project should support RTL and unity custom map. So I need to decide set minimum sdk correctly. I know 19 covered %96.2 but there is %3.8 below 19. 
So What is the minimum SDK version should I choose? This account tells but there is no reason. https://twitter.com/minSdkVersion

Comment: please check minimum sdk version of the desired library/feature you want use

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the project you are doing, if your app is something that is needed/required by a person, no matter what age, I suggest that you should aim for API 15 (ICS) this will cover 99.7% of all devices as of today. If it's just an optional app, then you can aim for API 21 (Lollipop) so you can use the latest android APIs. Support for previous android version is somewhat painful.

You can check the live distribution here: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

### As of July 2019

[image]

- API 10 (Gingerbread) - 0.3%
- API 15 (Ice Cream Sandwich) - 0.3%
- API 16 (Jellybean) - 1.2%
- API 17 (Jellybean) - 1.5%
- API 18 (Jellybean) - 0.5%
- API 19 (KitKat) - 6.9%
- API 21 (Lollipop) - 3.0%
- API 22 (Lollipop) - 11.5%
- API 23 (Marshmallow) - 16.9%
- API 24 (Nougat) - 11.4%
- API 25 (Nougat) - 7.8%
- API 26 (Oreo) - 12.9%
- API 27 (Oreo) - 15.4%
- API 28 (Pie) - 10.4%

Comment: This is horrifying to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend minimum version should be 21.Because i feel google will soon black list android kitkat (Because most of the api are support from api level 21). As apple, when apple come-up with new version, Apple always support n-2 minimum version.Google will also soon migrate to same approach.

Comment: Google will never use the same approach because contrary to Apple, Google does not control the hardware and operating system updates. Google has to support more operating system versions because phone vendors typically only provide two years of operating system updates for any given device.

Answer (score 0):

You should analyse what SDK using users that you want to reach. Most of features that requires higher sdks can be implemented with lower ones it just require more work.